# Is it possible to be permanently killed by the Black Death?

Tags: diablo

It is a well known fact that one of the most dangerous monsters in the original Diablo is actually one that you encounter relatively early - a variant of the zombie monster known as Black Death.

These can be encountered on levels 3-5 and seem harmless enough, as they don't do a lot of damage and are just as slow as all the other types of zombies, but each time they hit you they take away 1 HP out of your maximum, **permanently** (I didn't realize this until a friend tipped me off, at which point I avoided these like, well, the black death).

Thinking about this now, I am wondering just how low you can get your HP by getting hit by these monsters. Specifically, I wonder what were to happen if you manage to reduce your maximum HP to 1 and then get hit by one of these (though I imagine this is tricky to pull off, seeing how at a certain point each hit by these would kill you off completely)?

Comment: Similarly, avoid certain shrines which can reduce your maximum mana by 10%: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47663/what-shrines-are-good-for-me

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**No**: the lowest possible total HP is "**1**".

[image: Black Death sprite][image: Black Death sprite][image: Black Death sprite][image: Black Death sprite][image: Black Death sprite]

**Black Death hit for more HP (6-22 HP/hit) than they deduct from your max HP (1 HP/hit).**<sup>[1](http://www.diablowiki.com/Black_Death_(Diablo_I))</sup> In most cases, their final blow kills you before their max HP modifier could. In single-player, all deaths "permanent" kills, as you're forced to load from your last save or start over.<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR6JB.png)</sup> In multiplayer, you can restart naked at the nearest town (like in *Diablo II*'s multiplayer).

If you get tricky, you can use Mana Shield—a spell that deducts damage from mana instead of health<sup>[3](http://www.diablowiki.com/Mana_Shield_(Diablo_I))</sup>—to reduce your max HP to "1". **After this point, Mana Shielded Black Death hits only reduce mana, not health.** Likewise, your next unshielded Black Death hit kills you but does not further reduce your max HP:

[image: lowlife]

Comment: Hmm, yes, I see. My question is a little misleading. I'll edit it a little when I get back from work. Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: False, with Mana Shield you can be reduced below that. If I recall correctly you end up with 0 max health and die instantly upon restarting in town.

Comment: Also, deaths are not necessarily permanent. If you're playing on Battle.net or by yourself in "multiplayer" you can restart in town and recover your dropped items.

Comment: @Decency Now that's thinking outside the box. Thanks for the info, I hope this gets incorporated into the current answer (or maybe I'll go ahead and do some editing).

Comment: I tested it, and while Mana Shield brings you closer to 1 HP, you won't ever hit zero.